# How do I DROP column from database while being inside Django shell?

Tags: django, django-models

Here is the scenario:

- I don't have access to `psql` prompt.
- I do have access to `python manage.py shell` or `shell_plus`

Is it possible to drop a column of that database using Django internals? I know it's possible in theory.

Any insights are welcome.

Comment: Do you have access to the models.py file that the table is in? Then you could just delete the field and run `python manage.py makemirgrations`, `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Are you aware of the consequences? What's the purpose of droping a column in the python shell? If you just drop a column but keep the corresponding field in your models, it will bite you back later and you'll scream. Do as @Sam proposes: `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`. This has also the advantage when deploying the application, you can easy generate the database structure from the migrations.

Comment: If you have access to `python manage.py shell` you should have access to `python manage.py dbshell`.  If not, I'd like to know in which case access to the first would be possible, but access to the later not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It shouldn't be a challenge, As Cezar pointed out `python manage.py dbshell` should invoke the prompt just like `psql` would do.

If nothing else works you can still get through it since Django allows to execute arbitrary (raw) SQL from the shell. The below snippet should do it:

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("alter table table_name DROP column column_name")
```